# Proving $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ where $f_n(x)=\int_0^{1/n} n f(x-u) du.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be continuous, and define $\{f_n \}_{n=1}^\infty $ by $$f_n(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^{1/n} n f(x-u) du.$$

Then, prove that $$\forall x \in \mathbb R ; \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)= f(x).$$

I think this can be proved by definition.

---

Fix $x\in \mathbb R.$

Let $\epsilon >0$.

(I have to find some $N \in \mathbb N.$)

When $n \geqq N,$

\begin{align}
|f_n (x)-f(x)|
&=\left| \int_0^{1/n} n f(x-u)-nf(x) du\right| \\
&\leqq n \int_0^{1/n} |f(x-u)-f(x)| du.
\end{align}

If I could find $N\in \mathbb  N$ s.t. $n \geqq N \Rightarrow |f(x-u)-f(x)|< \epsilon,$ I come to conclusion.

I think I have to use the continuity of $f$ but I don't know how I can find such $N$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You basically have it. Choose $N$ such that $0<\frac{1}{N}<\delta$, where $\delta$ is such that $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Inside the integral, if $n\geq N$, then $u<\delta$.

Comment: First, your title is misleading. It says you want to talk about the continuity of $f_n$, when in reality, you want to talk about its convergence. I think you should edit the title. Secondly, since $f$ is continuous and $x$ is already fixed, can you not find some $\delta > 0$ such that for $\left| u \right| < \delta$, you get $\left| f \left( x - u \right) - f \left( x \right) \right| < \epsilon$? If you can do this, the rest is only a clever use of the Archimedean property.

Comment: The title was wrong. I edited. @Aniruddha_Deshmukh

Comment: I solved. Thank you.